# Npm stream-player causing fs dependency not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js

I am trying to use [stream-player npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-player)

I run `npm install stream-player` and added it in to my package.json.

I my app.js I added     `import streamPlayer from 'stream-player`. After that my app is not running anymore and I am receiving:

> This dependency was not found:
>
> fs in ./~/stream-player/lib/stream-player.js, ./~/request/lib/har.js and 2 others
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs

But I have the fs installed. Any ideas?

Comment: `fs` is built in module of `node.js`.  You don't have to install it from npm.

Comment: got it. But what is causing the error?

Comment: It seems like stream-player is designed for node, and not for use inside a browser

Comment: Just for debugger purpose, Add this two line in your app. `const fs = require('fs'); console.log(fs)` do you getting error for this two line ?

Comment: @RitwickDey I removed my code add it. I got similar erro:

This dependency was not found:

Comment: I suggest you to uninstall node.js and install again

Comment: Or just use NVM (http://nvm.sh)
There are some browser fs modules that use localStorage